How to compute disk I/O usage percentage in Windows, exactly like Task Manager, for the current process?
I'm trying to compute the disk I/O usage percentage for the current process in Windows, similar to what the Task Manager displays under the "Disk" column. However, I haven't been able to get an accurate match.
I used psutil.Process.io_counters() to retrieve the read/write byte counts for the current process, but it doesn't seem to align with what the Task Manager shows. Specifically, when using libraries like yara for file scanning, the io_counters read/write values don't seem to account for all the I/O operations correctly. It might be due to how YARA handles file reads in memory or how Windows tracks I/O for such operations.
What I need:
A method or tool to calculate the disk I/O usage percentage for the current process, in a way that matches the Windows Task Manager.
Preferably, a Python-based approach, but I'm open to any reliable solutions or libraries.
Insights into why psutil might not reflect accurate I/O stats for processes using specific libraries like YARA.
What I’ve tried:
Using psutil.Process.io_counters() to get read/write bytes, but the reported values don't match the Task Manager's disk usage.
Exploring system-level counters (e.g., Performance Counters in Windows), but I couldn't figure out how to map these to the Task Manager's percentage values.
Is there a way to reliably compute this disk I/O percentage for the current process? Or could someone clarify how Task Manager calculates this metric?

what i wonder is what is use of getting some value whose meaning is unknown, like you dont even know what is that percentage but just use it for comparison, so why would one like to know the exact percent if job was to see if disk is used more or less, btw i think % is speed vs max speed of disk

Active time is % of time the disk is not idle (exact phrase from tooltip)

You're right that the exact meaning of the percentage might not be clearly defined. However, the percentage provides a very good estimation of resource usage. After all, isn't it true that when a high percentage of resources is being utilized—based on these unspecified numbers and calculations—the system tends to freeze?
I'm running intensive processes that require me to monitor the system closely. This monitoring allows me to take necessary actions before the system experiences freezing or other critical issues. If you have a better idea I'm open to it.
Thanks for helping.

First word: as you mentioned to prevent system freezing, it is most likely that you want to monitor ram and cpu usage(now I am not one who is saying ram is performance), still for a task that works so much on a disk, you might have to consider monitoring disc.
Now for getting this data, I don't see a way psutil can do that exactly returning same the Taskmanager does, so use Windows Performance Counters win32pdh.
The code is below:
import time
import win32pdh
#current_process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
#process_name = current_process.name()
process_name = "explorer"  # Comment this

def get_count():
    try:
        # Counter path for % Idle Time

        counter_path_template = r"\Process({})\IO Data Bytes/sec"
        counter_path = counter_path_template.format(process_name)

        # Create a performance counter query
        query_handle = win32pdh.OpenQuery()
        counter = win32pdh.AddCounter(query_handle, counter_path)

        # Collect the initial data sample
        win32pdh.CollectQueryData(query_handle)
        time.sleep(1)  # Wait for the counter to update

        # Collect the second data sample for calculation
        win32pdh.CollectQueryData(query_handle)
        _, value = win32pdh.GetFormattedCounterValue(counter, win32pdh.PDH_FMT_DOUBLE)

        # Active Time (%) = 100 - Idle Time (%)
        val = value/1048576 #1024*1024
        # Clean up
        win32pdh.CloseQuery(query_handle)

        return val

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Press Ctrl+C to stop.")
    try:
        while True:
            val = get_count()
            if val is not None:
                print(f"Data Usage by {process_name}: {val} MB/s")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\nMonitoring stopped.")


The values of this code output match that of task manager, and the values are nearly same(not a decimal precision, but precise like +-2%). Tested while copying a large folder for test which I later deleted.
Uncomment the lines 3,4 comment line 5 for your case of monitoring the python program itself
Running this didn't cause any increase in memory with respect to time not running this code, so I think this should fit your purpose.
helper script:
import win32pdh

def list_all_counters(category):
    """Lists all counters and their instances for a given category."""
    try:
        counters, instances = win32pdh.EnumObjectItems(None, None, category, win32pdh.PERF_DETAIL_WIZARD)
        print(f"\n=== {category} Counters ===")
        for counter in counters:
            print(f"Counter: {counter}")
        if instances:
            print(f"\nInstances:")
            for instance in instances:
                print(f"  {instance}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error accessing category '{category}': {e}")

def query_counters(category):
    """Queries and prints the values of all counters in a category."""
    try:
        counters, instances = win32pdh.EnumObjectItems(None, None, category, win32pdh.PERF_DETAIL_WIZARD)
        query_handle = win32pdh.OpenQuery()
        counter_handles = []

        # Add counters for all instances
        for counter in counters:
            if instances:
                for instance in instances:
                    counter_path = f"\\{category}({instance})\\{counter}"
                    try:
                        handle = win32pdh.AddCounter(query_handle, counter_path)
                        counter_handles.append((handle, counter_path))
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(f"Could not add counter {counter_path}: {e}")
            else:
                counter_path = f"\\{category}\\{counter}"
                try:
                    handle = win32pdh.AddCounter(query_handle, counter_path)
                    counter_handles.append((handle, counter_path))
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Could not add counter {counter_path}: {e}")

        
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error accessing category '{category}': {e}")
    finally:
        if 'query_handle' in locals():
            win32pdh.CloseQuery(query_handle)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    categories = ["Process", "Processor", "Memory", "PhysicalDisk", "LogicalDisk"]
    for category in categories:
        list_all_counters(category)  # List counters and instances
        query_counters(category)    # Query and print counter values

Run this script to get all process_name(instance), all counters which you can use.
I assumed you need \Process({})\IO Data Bytes/sec change it if required with helper script.

Thank you so much for your answer! It really helped me understand how to compute disk I/O usage better. However, I’m trying to compute it specifically for my process (using YARA) and limit it to a specific physical drive. Could you adjust your solution to cover these aspects?
Also and more importantly, I’m curious—how did you come up with this answer? Did you use specific resources or past experience? Your insights would be really helpful. Thanks again!

Sorry if the changes may seem too trivial. I don't know anything about WMI and querying to it.  Just started searching in the area...

I have addressed how to access for specific physical drives in answer now, but I think you know the means of this site: ask single question in a post, and if it solves the question mark it as answer. Please don't build up new questions.

Btw. I refer docs, google search, chatgpt(I prompted more that 10 times to get this out+ Edited).

Thank you for your assistance. While your help has put me on the right track, I can't mark the question as solved yet. The original question specifically asked about measuring I/O disk usage for a single process, not the entire drive. The challenge is complicated by Yara's unusual background operations, which are designed to speed up processing by bypassing normal disk-to-memory data transfer methods, making it difficult to track.
I'll build upon your answer once I find a complete solution. with

Oh I understand, you where asking for single process,will check it out soon

@Pedram please check my edited answer, you can use lines 3,4 to monitor YARA itself in same python script
